# Finding values on a table in a webpage using Jsoup and Java where everything has a "td" tag

Tags: java, html, html-table, jsoup

I want to access table values on this website using Jsoup and Java:

http://mmcd.nmrfam.wisc.edu/test/cqsearch.py?cqid=cq_12391

For example, I want to access "5-(3,4-DICHLOROPHENYL)-6-METHYLPYRIMIDINE-2,4-DIAMINE" --> which comes after the table value "Name".

My solution for other problems of this nature would include looking for the header tag and then find the values of "td" under the th tag. However, this won't work in this scenario as everything within the table has a "td" tag.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can access certain values of the table as described earlier? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify which element you want to pick using CSS descriptors mentioned in [Selector documentation](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) like:

- `:eq(n)` where `n` is 0-based index sibling index,
- `:has(selector)`
- `:contains(text)`
- `:matches(regex)`

In case described by your question you could

- pick table which has `width="80%"` attribute,
- then from that table pick table row (`tr`)

  - which first cell (`td:eq(0)`) holds text `Name:` string.
- from that row (based on content of first cell) pick second cell (using `:eq(1)`)
- and get its text.

DEMO:

```
String url = "http://mmcd.nmrfam.wisc.edu/test/cqsearch.py?cqid=cq_12391";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements select = doc.select("table[width=80%] tr:has(td:matchesOwn(^Name:$)) td:eq(1)");
String name = select.text(); 

System.out.println(name);
```

Output: `5-(3,4-DICHLOROPHENYL)-6-METHYLPYRIMIDINE-2,4-DIAMINE`

I used `td:matchesOwn(^Name:$)` to make sure that `Name:` is entire text in td (since in regex `^` represents beginning of text and `$` end of text). This lets us eliminate cells containing text like `surname:` (if there ware any).